# Can a full bottle of liquor burst?

Tags: thermodynamics

I was watching TV when suddenly a full bottle of strong homemade liquor burst in the cupboard by itself. How was that possible? It was really creepy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it was fermented, then there may have been active yeast still producing carbon dioxide. The pressure from this may have caused the explosion.

If it was distilled spirits, the vapor pressure of ethyl alcohol at room temperature is not zero and rises with the temp. And the fluid itself will expand with increasing temp. So if the bottle was absolutely full (no airspace) and tightly stoppered, the expansion pressure may have caused it to burst.

Comment: Unlikely to be fermentation (killed by the time you are at the "strong liquor" stage). Very likely the result of not enough headroom, thermal expansion of the liquid, poof. You could improve this answer by calculating the pressure that can build up (from the difference in coefficient of thermal expansion between glass and alcohol, a reasonable assumption for the temperature rise, and the bulk modulus of the liquid).